# C++ COM interface callback in C#

Tags: c#, c++, com, ms-media-foundation

The issue I'm facing is from this code:
[Callback from a C++ COM DLL to a C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063202/callback-from-a-c-com-dll-to-a-c-sharp-application)

Notice that in the answer (in the C# code portion),

```
internal class EVRPresenterCallback : EmideeMediaFoundationLib.IEVRPresenterCallback
{
    public void PresentSurfaceCB(uint pSurface)
    {
    }
}
```

`PresentSurfaceCB` is declared with a void return type.

However, in the IDL, I've declared it as `HRESULT PresentSurfaceCB(...)`.

With this mismatch, the code actually works. *But* if I were to change the return type from `void` to `int` in C#'s interface declaration, I would end up with Access Violation in x86 mode but not x64 (x64 ABI does not pop anything from stack thus will not crash when return types mismatch). i.e.

```
internal class EVRPresenterCallback : EmideeMediaFoundationLib.IEVRPresenterCallback
{
    public int PresentSurfaceCB(uint pSurface)
    {
        // this crashes with AV after the callback is called!
        // WHY?
    }
}
```

I also found that I don't actually have to declare its guid for the interface to work.
Why not? I suspect the VTable is understood from the interface declaration? In which case, I should also be able to restructure my C++ code to move the IDL code back into C++?

```
// [ComVisible(true), ComImport, Guid("B92D8991-6C42-4e51-B942-E61CB8696FCB")] -- this is unnecessary - why?
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal interface IEVRPresenterCallback
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int PresentSurfaceCB(IntPtr pSurface);
}
```

Comment: The part which looks scary for me is that COM interface pointer argument is declared as `uint`; also WPF Media Kit has this declaration as well [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14333872/) which is presumably correct.